# sort a python list while maintaining its element's indices

Tags: python, sorting, asort

I need to sort a python list but the sort should not alter the index the elements had before the sort. There's a function called asort for this in php, but how to do it in python? Is there such a method? If not, how to do it in fewer line?

For instance, take following example:

```
$a = [1, 5, 2, 4];
print_r($a);
asort($a);
print_r($a);
```

Output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 4
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 4
    [1] => 5
)
```

Here 5 still has index 1 after `asort` but it has been sorted to the end.

I do have my own solution, which is: Create the indices as a list of integers. Then use [List Length] and [Series] to create this list. Then, sort both numeric values and indices synchronously, i.e. using the same Sort component. Although, this is not exactly what `asort()` does, but pretty close.

Is there a better way to do it? That too in fewer lines? Maybe a built-in method? An efficient way can be preferred over fewer lines.

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused, the [`asort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) docs say this is used for associative arrays (dicts), but you're using this for lists, so what's the connection?

Comment: Please explain with an example and what you have already tried.

Comment: How can you sort a list without changing the indices of elements? Unless the list is already sorted

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ In PHP arrays serve both as numerically indexed lists *and* associative dicts.

Comment: @deceze Thank you. These are important details that should've come from OP. This is really unclear...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ It's often confusing to people coming from PHP that other languages often don't have associative *ordered* maps…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary difference between PHP and Python is that PHP arrays are both associative and ordered, while in Python you can either have an *ordered* `list` *or* an *associative* `dict`, but not both in one data structure.*

<sub>* There's `OrderedDict` and `dict` is starting to become ordered itself, but let's stick with the primitives.</sub>

So fundamentally you'll need to think of different data structures. The typical way to do this is to have a list of tuples, with one tuple value representing your former index and the other value the former value:

```
[(0, 'foo'), (1, 'bar'), ...]
```

You can get to that from a normal list using `enumerate`:

```
l = list(enumerate(my_list))  # ['foo', 'bar'] → [(0, 'foo'), (1, 'bar')]
```

And you can sort it in the process:

```
l = sorted(enumerate(my_list), key=lambda i: i[1])  # → [(1, 'bar'), (0, 'foo')]
```

Here `lambda i: i[1]` simply sorts by the second tuple value, i.e. your former value. You can replace that with `itemgetter(1)` from the `operator` module for brevity, or adjust as necessary for your sorting condition.

If you want to turn that into an associative data structure again, use `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import itemgetter

l = OrderedDict(sorted(enumerate(my_list), key=itemgetter(1)))
```

Comment: okay, I get what you're saying. I feel like accepting the answer but I might need to see a couple of things. Gimme a moment

Comment: Alright man. This makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

First you connect the original values to its index list. Then you sort it and the original indexes are attched to the new sorted values. Finally unzip them to get both lists.

```
i_xs                 = [(x, i) for (i, x) in enumerate(xs)]
s                    = sorted(i_xs)
sorted_xs, index_lst = unzip(s)
```

Using this

```
def unzip(ls):
    if isinstance(ls, list):
        if not ls:
            return [], []
        else:
            xs, ys = zip(*ls)

        return list(xs), list(ys)
    else:
        raise TypeError
```

Example. In:

```
[34, 23424, 1212, -2324, 34353]
```

Out:

```
[-2324, 34, 1212, 23424, 34353]

[3, 0, 2, 1, 4]
```